# pass post value in ajax data parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass the value of a post method using form method in my ajax call. When a print the value of my variable which should contains the value of the input i got undefined.

This is my form method

```
<a href="javascript:DoPost()">GO</a>
  <form action="allproducts.php" id="link_code" name="postlink" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="link_code" name="name_link" value="2"> 
  </form>
```

Below my ajax call

```
link_data();
function link_data()
{
    $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
    var name_link = $('#link_code').attr("value");
    console.log(name_link);
    
    $.ajax({
        url:"action.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{name_link:name_link},
        success:function(data){
            $('.filter_data').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have duplicated ids on form and hidden input. They must be unique

Comment: I remove the hidden type and changed the ids but still got uundefined on my console. on my php code i have checked that the value has been posted corectly

Comment: Using attr('value') should really just be `val()` which gets the value property

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ID from the form element.  That element does not have a value attribute.

Also, I would recommend using .val() instead of attr('value').

Comment: My error is that i was trying to get the value of my post from another page.

Comment: I solve it by using window.location.href to get my value from the other page.